# reactjs error while consuming the graphql API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, graphql

Trying to consume the graphql API in react js application. not sure whether this approach is correct or not.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "./styles.css";
import axios from 'axios';

const appBaseUrl = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8099/graphql'
});

const tagslist = ` {
  getTags
  {
    id
    tagName
    tagDesc
    tagVersion
    tagVersion
  }
}
`;

class TagsController extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tags: []};
    this.headers = [
      { key: "id", label: "Tag Id" },
      { key: "tagName", label: "Tag Name" },
      { key: "tagDesc", label: "Tag Description" },
      { key: "tagVersion", label: "Tag Version" }
    ];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    appBaseUrl
      .post('', { query: tagslist })
      .then(result =>
        this.setState(() => ({
          tags: result
        })),
      );
  }

  render() {
    console.log("...... url builder ......")
    const { tags } = this.state;
    return (
      <table border ="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
                    {
                        this.headers.map(function(h) {
                            return (
                                <th key = {h.key}>{h.label}</th>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                    </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {tags &&
            tags.data &&
            tags.data.getTags.map(function(item, key) {
              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  <td>{item.tagName}</td>
                  <td>{item.tagDesc}</td>
                  <td>{item.tagVersion}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default TagsController;
```

Here exception below.

> ×
>       Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>
> ```
> TagsController.render
>   src/TagsController.js:59
>   56 | }
>   57 | </tr>
>   58 |    </thead>
>   59 |    <tbody>
>      | ^  60 |      {tags &&
>   61 |        tags.data &&
>   62 |        tags.data.getTags.map(function(item, key) {
> View compiled
> ▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
> (anonymous function)
> src/TagsController.js:35
>   32 | 
>   33 | componentDidMount() {
>   34 |   appBaseUrl
>   35 |     .post('', { query: tagslist })
>      | ^  36 |     .then(result =>
>   37 |       this.setState(() => ({
>   38 |         tags: result
> ```

Excepted response from the API as below.

```
{
    "data": {
        "getTags": [
            {
                "id": "ef718cce-1269-4fbd-827c-832f7824c025",
                "tagName": "Veera6",
                "tagDesc": "Test Tag6",
                "tagVersion": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "0cda5ae9-e287-4666-804a-03f25e642d1f",
                "tagName": "Veera9",
                "tagDesc": "Test Tag9",
                "tagVersion": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "31f8f042-dbc0-4dbf-ada8-b94c7e2d2a39",
                "tagName": "Veera8",
                "tagDesc": "Test Tag8",
                "tagVersion": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "6292054c-8bfc-4d2d-b2f8-92e2bac5a578",
                "tagName": "Veera7",
                "tagDesc": "Test Tag7",
                "tagVersion": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "c6756e5c-8fa5-40a9-ab92-5242bda97de3",
                "tagName": "Veera10",
                "tagDesc": "Test Tag10",
                "tagVersion": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Basically i am trying to consume the graphql query API and display the result list with the react js application but getting the error as above. Looks like i am missing something when consume the graphql api and constructing the graphql query parameter

any help is really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

`tags` in the state won't be an `array` while the data is requested.
You need to add another conditional to show a loading message while the data is requested.

```
componentDidMount() {
this.setState(() => ({ loading: true }))
    appBaseUrl
      .post('', { query: tagslist })
      .then(result =>
        this.setState(() => ({
          tags: result,
          loading: false
        })),
      );
  }

render() {
    console.log("...... url builder ......")
    const { tags, loading } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return "Loading data..."
    }
}
```

You can find a lot of idea over the Internet, for example: http://nikolay.rocks/2017-06-18-better-redux-loading